# How do I put source code to Visual Studio code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I saw a portfolio website on YouTube. In that the youtuber said "the source code is in the description using the source code you can take the whole coding in your system and edit to make it yours". Now I want to put the source code(html css) to visual studio code but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone tell me how to do it as soon as possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question. As far as I understood that you want to open the folder that includes html and css file in VSCode. So to that open your editor and from toolbar `File>Open Folder` and choose the destination folder.

Comment: Hi Raj, welcome to the community. Please notice that this is not a site to ask premature questions. Questions must show an effort from the OP. Also try to make questions more clear exposing what you want to do, what you tried, and what you got.

Comment: I can tell you tomorrow, now I don't have time

Answer (score 1):

[image]

click on **Add Folder** after that browse which folder you want click it and open, done you can now edit your code